# How to aling a picture right, middled?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu structure:

http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/248/image4.gif

some menu(s) has sub menu(s), in this case I need that little red arrow. But as you can see, it goes to new line for the longest item; it's not centered. This is what I tried:

```
<a href="/fax">&nbsp;
  <span>flick&nbsp;</span><span style="float: right; vertical-align: middle;"><img src="/design/right.gif" width="4" height="7" /></span>
</a>
```

(no line breaks and spaces in real code, just to be easier to read)

In this case the arrow do goes right, but not in the middle but on top - in case of last menu item it goes bottom :S

Comment: Please paste your code and all css on http://jsfiddle.net/ That way we can see exactly what you have right now and how to fix your result.

Answer (score 1):

Give the a `line-heigth: 20px;` (example.. play with different heights according to your speccs). Only then will the vertical align work.

Additionally: whats with the `&nbsp;` and height and width attributes. You are using css, use it everywhere.

Replace the   on the a with `style="left: 1em;"`. 
Replace the   on the span with `style="padding-right: 1em;"`. 
Replace the height/width properties with their css equivalent.

Comment: It should. Though all elements in there should have the vertical-align: middle. Also: give your container (the parent of the A) a fixed with that is big enough and make the a `display:inline-block; width: 100%;`

Answer (score 1):

I would add position: relative to a tag and position: absolute for image.

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to add float:left to first span as like given below.

```
<a href="/fax">&nbsp;<span style="float:left;">flick&nbsp;</span><span style="float: right; vertical-align: middle;"><img src="D:/wamp/www/xplifeline/application/images/default.jpg" width="4" height="7" /></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li>Menu 1
    <ul class="nav first">
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
        <li>Menu 4
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>Menu 1</li>
            <li>Menu 2</li>
            <li>Menu 3</li>
            <li>Menu 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Menu 2</li>
<li>Menu 3</li>
<li>Menu 4</li>
```

from here: http://jsfiddle.net/y9jbQ/

now it looks:

```
<span style="float: left; line-heigth: 40px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">&nbsp;menu&nbsp;</span><span style="float: right; line-heigth: 40px; vertical-align: middle;"><img src="/design/right.gif" width="4" height="7" /></span>
```

now the result: http://s12.postimage.org/muw3hehyh/Image4.gif?noCache=1353932739